# Google Tag Manager Causing Blank Image At Bottom of Page

Tags: html, css, wordpress

When adding Google Tags to my Wordpress site, a blank image is displaying on the screen at the bottom of the page. How can I either hide or eliminate this image as it has not class or ID?

I have tried to place the Google Tag in different sections of the code (header, body, footer, etc.).

I am expecting the page to render as normal without the extra added image at the bottom of the page. The page is including an unwanted blank image at the bottom of the page.

Here is the page: https://wearewaterproofing.com. The code in the header:

```
    <!-- Placement: Paste this code as high in the <head> of the page as 
    possible. -->  

    <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
    <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s) 
    [0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js? 
    id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-WDGLSGL');</script> 
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

And here is the code immediately following the body tag:

```
    <!-- Placement: Additionally, paste this code immediately after the 
    opening <body> tag. -->  

    <!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
    <noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM- 
    WDGLSGL"
    height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe> 
    </noscript>
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
```

Comment: You need to share your code, and a minimal example.The question is useless without them.

Comment: Thanks..It was an oversight on my part. It has been added to the question now. Thanks for the help

Comment: That image is coming from BidAgent, it's not Google at all. Check your other plugins.

Comment: BidAgent returns the conversion pixel(?) for the google tag manager. (I am new to google tag manager and trying to solve this issue on the fly). The img property on my site is set to width = 100%. The pixel should render as a 1x1 pixel but is instead rendering as 100% of the page. Any thoughts on how to correct?

Comment: Check your GTM containers. Try this CSS to rectify the image issue: `body > img { display: none }`

Comment: @BenM Thanks for the code....It works as a hack to make the image disappear.